# "No such file or directory" Error while downloading SQLite on Mac, how do I fix this?

Tags: sqlite, download

I am trying to download SQLite for Mac (OSx el capitan) using terminal command and came across this error, how do I fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7K8K.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please include the error message here, as plain text, not as picture. That way your post is easier to read and if someone runs into the same problem, they can find your post in a web search.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to your question... you need a space between `./configure` and `--prefix`

```
./configure --prefix ....
```

Not sure why you would download it though as it is already shipped from Apple with OS X. And if you want a newer version, you would be better off installing it via `homebrew`.